# Angular 2: Apply Validator.required validation on some condition

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a angular 2 form wherein I have to make a field required on some condition like:

```
description:  ['', Validators.required]
```

This description field will be required only on some type of a condition like:

```
if(true){descReq = true};
```

How can I achieve this, please suggest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is that other condition?

Answer (score 8):

You can add or remove a validator based on the the value of another control on the form:

```
    testForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.testForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        condition: [''],
        description: ['']
      });

      this.testForm.controls['condition'].valueChanges.subscribe(result => {
        if (result) {
          this.testForm.controls['description'].setValidators(Validators.required);
          this.testForm.controls['description'].updateValueAndValidity();
        } else {
          this.testForm.controls['description'].setValidators(null);
          this.testForm.controls['description'].updateValueAndValidity();
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `descReq` needs to be evaluated at run-time (rather than when its initialized), then perhaps you should create a custom validator:

```
import { ValidatorFn, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
interface ValidationResult {
    [key:string]:boolean;
}
function customValidator(condition: { required:boolean }) {
     return (control: AbstractControl) :ValidationResult  => {
         return condition.required && 
             (control.value == undefined || 
              control.value == null || 
              control.value.trim() =='') ? 
              {
                 'required': true
              }: null;

       }

}
```

Use like this:

```
description:  ['', customValidator(this.reqd)]
```

where `reqd` has been initialized earlier, and maybe even data-bound:

```
reqd = { required: false };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it throws me an error:
'Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'required' of undefined'

Comment: you need to initialize `this.condition`

Comment: It's initialized in the constructor. I console logged the this.condition inside both constructor and required() method. It is initialized within constructor but gives undefined inside the method.

Comment: ah, my bad. Yes, passing a fn reference like that will change the meaning of `this`.  I've updated it to be a factory function - should work.

Comment: method not getting invoked when the condition changes. Like when the condition changes from false to true, this function should get called. Not happening in this case?

Comment: Seems to work for me. https://github.com/pixelbits-mk/angular2-starter-app/tree/CodeKaro .

Answer (score 0):

You should set the validator on the field *imperatively* vs *declaratively*.

**Declaratively (your current code):**

```ts
const description = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
```

**Imperatively:**

```ts
const description = new FormControl('');
if (someCondition) {
  description.setValidators(Validators.required);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **Validators.requiredTrue**

`description:  [false, Validators.requiredTrue]`