# Angular 2 - Validate fields with condition if checkbox is checked

Tags: validation, angular

I have a checkbox. If it is checked it will let the user to select on the option and if it is unchecked it will let the user to add a new option using a textfield.

I have a code in typescript to validate the fields. Below is my code:

```
this.complexForm = this.fb.group({
    "name":[null,Validators.required],
    "isoAlpha2":[null,Validators.required],
    "isoAlpha3":[null,Validators.required],
    "isoNumeric":[null,Validators.required],
    "languageId":[1,false],
    "currencyId":[null,Validators.required],
    "geoLocationId":[false,false],
    "latitude":[null,Validators.required],
    "longitude":[null,Validators.required],
    "status":["Active",false]
  });
```

The default is to let the user to input `latitude and longitude fields`. This means that the checkbox is unchecked.

When user check the checkbox the user will be allowed to select to listed geo locations in a dropdown.

Now my problem is, if I checked the checkbox the `latitude` and `longitude` field does not need validation and when if I checked the checkbox the `geoLocationId` field will not need a validation.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238639/angular-2-apply-validator-required-validation-on-some-condition/42239003#42239003). I have put an example of conditional validations one of the answers. Maybe that could help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="handleValidation($event)"
```

**Component:**

```
handleValidation($event: any): void {
  const latitude: FormControl = this.complexForm.get('latitude');
  const longitude: FormControl =   this.complexForm.get('longitude');
  const geoLocationId: FormControl =   this.complexForm.get('geoLocationId');
  const requiredValidator: any = Validators.required;
  const nullValidator: any = Validators.nullValidator;

  if ($event.target.value) {
    latitude.setValidators(nullValidator);
    longitude.setValidators(nullValidator);
    geoLocationId.setValidators(requiredValidator);
  } else {
    latitude.setValidators(requiredValidator);
    longitude.setValidators(requiredValidator);
    geoLocationId.setValidators(nullValidator);
    // Maybe you to clean the value.. so it must be `geoLocationId.patchValue('');
  }

  latitude.updateValueAndValidity();
  longitude.updateValueAndValidity();
  geoLocationId.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

**PS:** Not tested.