# Angular2 dynamically update validation rules

Tags: validation, angular

In Angular2 I need to modify validation rules dynamically.On the selection of a value from a dropdown validation rules will be fetched from the database and they would be like
    `{filedName : FirstName, required : 1}.` 
Currenlty I'm suing template driven form validation but after searching a bit I have realised that I would have to use model driven approach. Any ideas on how to do that?

> **Edit**

Answer by JayChase to the above mentioned question seems the right one in my scenario. But I have couple of queries.I can remove all validation rules by passing null to setValidators but how can I just remove required field validation.And is it possible for me to modify validation rules in template driven approach.

> **Update**

I'm able to update validation rules by following JayChase's answer.I did not use async validation as it would have costed me too much server calls. So now the issue is how to update just the required field validation rule.Right now I'm removing all validations from the control.

```
form.controls["fieldName"].setValidators(null)
```

Any help on that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Apply Validator.required validation on some condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238639/angular-2-apply-validator-required-validation-on-some-condition)

Comment: Since your server is driving the validation, it might make more sense to simply switch to async validation