# Conditional Form Validations for Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to set conditional form validations on an angular reactive form and need some help.

I have a form control where the user sets their entity type to either Individual or Business

```
<select formControlName="entity">
  <option [value]="individual">Individual</option>
  <option [value]="business">Business</option>
</select>
```

I then have form inputs that display or hide based upon what entity is selected:

```
<div *ngIf="myForm.controls.entity.value == individual>
  <input formControlName="fullName" />
</div>

<div *ngIf="myForm.controls.entity.value == business>
  <input formControlName="businessName" />
</div>
```

How can I make both inputs required only if the corresponding entity is selected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Apply Validator.required validation on some condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238639/angular-2-apply-validator-required-validation-on-some-condition)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the attribute [formControl]="name_of_your_input_control" assuming this html is within a formGroup element

```
<div [hidden]="isBusiness">
  <input [formControl]="fullName" />
</div>

<div [hidden]="!isBusiness">
  <input [formControl]="businessName" />
</div>
```

in your ts class :

After you create your form add this :

```
isBusiness:boolean = false;
//...
this.nameOfYourForm.valueChanges.subscribe((newForm) => {
     this.isBusiness = (newForm.controls.entity.value == 'business');
     if(this.isbusiness){
        this.nameOfYourForm.controls.fullName.setValidators(/*your new validation here*/);
           //set the validations to null for the other input
     }else{       
           this.nameOfYourForm.controls.businessName.setValidators(/*your new validation here*/);
           //set the validations to null for the other input
     } 
});
```

Notice that I changed your *ngIf to [hidden] as *ngIf will completely remove the controle from your template where [hidden] will just apply a display none.

You can also add a change listener on a specific control instead of the whole form, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Or you can define your control at runtime:
<code>
isBusiness:boolean = false;
//...
this.nameOfYourForm.valueChanges.subscribe((newForm) => {
     this.isBusiness = (newForm.controls.entity.value == 'business');
     if(this.isbusiness){
        this.nameOfYourForm.registerControl('yourControl', new FormControl('', [Validators]));
     }else{       
           this.nameOfYourForm.removeControl('yourControl');
})</code>

Answer (score 1):

I have an other version:

**HTML**

```
<select #select formControlName="entity">
  <option  [ngValue]="Individual">Individual</option>
  <option  [ngValue]="Business">Business</option>
</select>
<br>
<div *ngIf="select.value[0]  === '0'">
  <input #input [required]="select.value[0] === '0'" formControlName="fullName" />
  <span *ngIf="!myForm.get('fullName').valid">Invalid</span>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bu4cc?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: the template should be used for validation logic only in Template-driven forms

Comment: @squirrelsareduck, the solution that I propose is for reactive forms, only the check is done in the template. There is nothing wrong with it, I would say there are some advantages. Otherwise, prove it

Answer (score 1):

```js
const formGroup= new FormGroup({
    type: new FormControl(), 
    businessForm: new FormGroup({
      businessName: new Formcontrol('')
    }), 
    individualForm:new FormGroup({
      individualName: new Formcontrol('')
    })
}); 

formType$ = this.formGroup.controls['type'].valueChanges;
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">

   <div formGroupName="businessForm" *ngIf="(formType$ | async) =='business'">       
     <input formControlName="businessName"/>
   </div>

   <div formGroupName="individualForm" *ngIf="(formType$ | async) =='individual'">
     <input formControlName="individualName"/>
   </div>

</form>
```